# Python - Sting list with no single quotation

Tags: python, arrays, string, list, quotes

I have a string that I want to add to a list, but i do not want the single quotes to be added to the list item.

I have the following string:

```
arcpy.Point(2748877.71681,-3785391.73006), arcpy.Point(2731755.82248,-3765823.85082), arcpy.Point(2751323.70172,-3758485.8961)
```

I want to not add this into a list, but without the single quotation marks. I am currently getting this:

```
['arcpy.Point(2748877.71681,-3785391.73006), arcpy.Point(2731755.82248,-3765823.85082), arcpy.Point(2751323.70172,-3758485.8961)']
```

I need to have the following output rather:

```
[arcpy.Point(2748877.71681,-3785391.73006), arcpy.Point(2731755.82248,-3765823.85082), arcpy.Point(2751323.70172,-3758485.8961)]
```

I have tried both of the following, however, they both do not work:

```
>>> area_array = "arcpy.Point(2748877.71681,-3785391.73006), arcpy.Point(2731755.82248,-3765823.85082), arcpy.Point(2751323.70172,-3758485.8961)"
>>> area_array_list = ["{}".format(area_array)]
>>> area_array_list_str ="[{}]".format(area_array)
['arcpy.Point(2748877.71681,-3785391.73006), arcpy.Point(2731755.82248,-3765823.85082), arcpy.Point(2751323.70172,-3758485.8961)']
"[arcpy.Point(2748877.71681,-3785391.73006), arcpy.Point(2731755.82248,-3765823.85082), arcpy.Point(2751323.70172,-3758485.8961)]"
```

The `area_array_list` gives me the list but with the single quotes and the `area_array_list_str` just gives me a string result (not a list).

Thanks for any help.

Comment: The quotations are not part of the string. They are showing that it is represented as a string, so you cannot avoid them. It will be `'[text1, text2...]'`, `['text1, text2,...']` or, which you have left out but is the most reasonable `['tex1', 'text2', ...]`.

Comment: So is there no way to avoid them and get the result that I need?

Comment: What do you _really_ want. When you print your sting, it will show without the quotation marks.

Comment: You can "eval" a string to turn it into a Python object.  But where did you get your strings originally?

Comment: It is from a json file that i need in a different format:
"geometry": {
   "rings": [[[2748877.716811686,
   -3785391.7300581136],
   [2731755.8224758105,
   -3765823.8508171136],
   [2751323.7017168105,
   -3758485.896101739]]],
   "spatialReference": {
    "wkid": 102100
   }
  }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As has been hinted at, you should use `eval` with the `list` constructor to get this into a list. Simply using `[]` won't work since the eval will create a tuple, not a list.

```
list(eval('arcpy.Point(2731755.82248,-3765823.85082), arcpy.Point(2751323.70172,-3758485.8961)'))
```

The output won't be exactly what you have listed there since the functions will execute (rest assured what you listed is impossible without any quotes), but it should be just as usable.

Comment: Thanks very much Peter G. This is working for me now.